# Laravel fortify two factor authentication, enforce confirm code after two factors authentication enabled

Tags: laravel, fortify, two-factor-authentication

I'd like to ask user input the verification code after the two factors authentication is enabled.

To be more specific,  when post /user/two-factor-authentication success, the two factory is enabled, and now user can access resource without provide verification code, so I'd like to ask user confirm the code immediately, but I didn't find any document about this, is it possible to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have approached it by the following code in FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    Fortify::authenticateThrough(function (Request $request) {
            return array_filter([
                config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
                Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication()) ? RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class : null,
                AttemptToenter code hereAuthenticate::class,
                PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
            ]);
        });
```